# How to pass filename to function and loop through and crop images?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying to crop a list of images. The list is stored in a txt file.

I run through the txt file and store the img urls into an array

```
Array ( [0] => img001.jpg [1] => img002.jpg [2] => img003.jpg [3] => img004.jpg )
```

The .php, .txt, and .jpg images are all in the same folder and there a IMG2 subfolder.

I'm running this locally.

I was getting an error loading file, but now I just get a blank screen.

Can someone help me make this loop through the files in an array crop them. I realize that in the example below i'm just sending one value from $lines[1], thats because I can't even get that to work.

Once that works then adding a FOR loop should be straight forward.

Thanks

```
    <?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$fd = fopen ("files.txt", "r");
while (!feof ($fd))
{
   $buffer = fgets($fd, 4096);
   $lines[] = $buffer;
}
fclose ($fd); 

print_r($lines);

$imgurl = $lines[1]; 

processImage($imgurl);  //or below line doesn't work
//foreach ($lines as $imgurl) processImage(trim($imgurl));

Function processImage($imgurl) {
    //load the image

    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgurl);

    if (!$img) { /* See if it failed */
        $img  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30); /* Create a black image */
        $bgc = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
        $tc  = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
        imagefilledrectangle($img, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);
        /* Output an errmsg */
        imagestring($img, 1, 5, 5, "Error loading $imgurl", $tc);
    }
    return $img;

    $b_top = 0;
    $b_btm = 0;
    $b_lft = 0;
    $b_rt = 0;

    //top
    for(; $b_top < imagesy($img); ++$b_top) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, $b_top) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; //out of the 'top' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //bottom
    for(; $b_btm < imagesy($img); ++$b_btm) {
      for($x = 0; $x < imagesx($img); ++$x) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $x, imagesy($img) - $b_btm-1) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; //out of the 'bottom' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //left
    for(; $b_lft < imagesx($img); ++$b_lft) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, $b_lft, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; //out of the 'left' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //right
    for(; $b_rt < imagesx($img); ++$b_rt) {
      for($y = 0; $y < imagesy($img); ++$y) {
        if(imagecolorat($img, imagesx($img) - $b_rt-1, $y) != 0xFFFFFF) {
           break 2; //out of the 'right' loop
        }
      }
    }

    //copy the contents, excluding the border
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($img)-($b_lft+$b_rt), imagesy($img)-($b_top+$b_btm));

    imagecopy($newimg, $img, 0, 0, $b_lft, $b_top, imagesx($newimg), imagesy($newimg));

    //finally, output the image
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($newimg);

    // Save the image
    $newname = "t_".$imgurl;
    imagejpeg($newimg, $newname);

    // Free up memory   
    imagedestroy($newimg);
    imagedestroy($img);


}

?>
```

Comment: just do `foreach ($lines as $imgurl) processImage(trim($imgurl));`

Comment: That doesn't work.  I dont' know why, but passing the Filename string to the function doens't seem work.

Comment: Thanks. I used your foreach line instead or For

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere at the top of your image processing function, you have the line:

```
return $img;
```

So that´s as far as it gets, it always returns from the function from there, the code after that is never reached.

Just removing that line should get you a lot further.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.  Yours and Francesco's response combined got me the answer i needed.